# Can't connect to mongodb attlas with cube.js

Tags: cube.js

In cube.js when i try to connect to mongodb atlas I get this error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xxxxx-xxxxx.mongodb.net 
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
```

my .env fiel:

```
CUBEJS_DB_HOST=xxxxx-xxxxx.mongodb.net
CUBEJS_DB_NAME=MyDatabase
CUBEJS_DB_USER=myUser
CUBEJS_DB_PASS=myPassword
CUBEJS_WEB_SOCKETS=true
CUBEJS_DB_TYPE=mongobi
CUBEJS_API_SECRET=mysecret
CUBEJS_DB_SSL=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your `CUBEJS_DB_HOST` and `CUBEJS_DB_PORT` settings. Please see https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/bi-connection/.